# SSO between Sitecore and Custom MVC Application

Tags: site-configuration

We got a requirement of enabling Single sign on between a Sitecore Instance and another MVC Application.
It would be helpful if someone can help me in getting a way to implement this?
(Both of the applications would be hosted on Internet)

Comment: There are many different SSO systems out there - have you tried researching them? Please ask more specific questions - this one might have a miriade of answers depending on your particular needs and architecture.

Comment: Even though I voted to close this question I will post an answer. As a good starting point you can try researching CAS - [Central Authentication Service](https://www.apereo.org/projects/cas) Please note this is only one of the options and I would strongly recommend speding some time on researching other possibilities and choosing the best one.